# How can I perform math on last x characters of string and update text box on the fly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an app where a user scans or types in a starting barcode, and the ending barcode is automatically calculated based on a quantity value.

It works fine when the starting barcode is entirely numeric, it does the math and includes leading zeroes so the end code is the correct length.

My problem is that some small percentage of the barcodes are not entirely numeric.

The barcodes are 14 characters long. The last 5 characters will always be numeric and quantities will rarely exceed a few hundred and never go high enough that we spill into the 6th digit.

I'm not a javascript expert by any means, and just getting what I have now working strained my skills -- I'm hoping the community here can help me out :)

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //leading zero fill function for barcodes
  function pad(num, size) {
    var s = "00000000000000" + num;
    return s.substr(s.length - size);
  }
  //Function to do BC math: starting number + quantity -1 (since it's inclusive) = end. 
  function updateCode() {
    var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('.quantity').val();
    var barstart = $(this).closest('tr').find('.barstart').val();
    var end = pad(parseInt(barstart, 10) + parseInt(quantity - 1, 10), 14);
    $(this).parent().next().find('.barend').val(end);
  }
  $(document).on("change, keyup", ".barstart", updateCode);
});
```

*Edit*  Trying to insert the HTML again:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<table id="formtable">
<tr>
<td><input class="quantity" size="6" id="qty_1" name="qtyid_1" value="123" type="text"></td>
<td><input class="barstart" size="15" maxlength="14" id="barstartid_1" name="barstart_1" value="" placeholder="Barcode Start" type="text"></td>
<td><input class="barend" size="15" maxlength="14" id="barendid_1" name="barend_1" value="" placeholder="Barcode End" type="text"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g1p2xh6y/1/

The users can live without it, but it'll save them some headaches (and help me make a good impression - this is a new gig) if I can get it working, so I greatly appreciate any help the community can offer :)

Thanks!

Comment: What input data do you have problems with? When are the barcodes not entirely numeric?

Comment: Is`barstart` your variable that holds the barcode?

Comment: Sorry, the HTML didn't come through in the posting, but it's in the jsfiddle. There are 3 text fields with classes barstart, barend, and quantity applied.

A barcode is usually something like 46180400117192 but can sometimes be something like 4FCS0000166211 - Just depends on what prefixes the end recipients specified, I guess.

Comment: @PeterMader When a barcode like 4FCS0000166211 is applied, the end barcode becomes calculated to 00000000000NaN since it's attempting to do math on a non-numeric value.   I'm looking for a way to make the calculation only look at the last 5 characters, or ignore the non-numeric values while retaining them in their correct places in the end barcode field, so 4FCS0000166211 with a quantity of 30 would fill in the end barcode value as 4FCS0000166240

Comment: `parseInt( '4FCS0000166211'.slice(-5) )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @admcfajn - I didn't know the slice() function existed, and that resolved it for me. I had to move the zero padding to the suffix, and remove it from the end value, but since it's pulling the prefix instead of doing math, that's no problem.

Here's the updated function:

```
function updateCode() {
        var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('.quantity').val();
        var barstart = $(this).closest('tr').find('.barstart').val();
        var barprefix = barstart.slice(0,barstart.length-5);
      var barendsuffix = pad(parseInt(barstart.slice(-5),10)+parseInt(quantity-1,10),5);
        $(this).parent().next().find('.barend').val(barprefix+barendsuffix);
}
```